# Align <a> centered and <img> on the left, both vertically centered inside a <td>

Tags: html, css, html-table

I would like to display an image left aligned (with some padding at the left/right) but vertically centered in the table cell, while keeping the text centered both horizontally and vertically.

JSFiddle complete example:

https://jsfiddle.net/6bsgkytq/

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <img title="Out of stock" src="..."><!-- This image may or may not exist -->
    <a href="">4000.4</a>
  </td>
  <td>Lemon soda</td>
  <td>10/10/2021</td>
  <td>London, United Kingdom</td>
  <td>Waiting</td>
</tr>
```

```css
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Using this code, the result is like this:

[image: Current result]

I would like instead:

1. To have the **text centered** on the cell (both horizontally and vertically), regardless of the presence/absence of the image; I could put the image as the `td` background but I don't want, because I would like the `title` attribute to be displayed as a tooltip with further info
2. To have the **image vertically centered** but left aligned
3. Have a **padding** on the left of the **image** and possible on the right (by increasing the column width - now fixed at 90px - if it is too small to handle image and text)

Like so:

[image: Desired result]

I would prefer to avoid javascript and stick with HTML/CSS only.

Comment: Put the image in a separate td.

Comment: @Grumpy I don't like so, because I would need to merge the thead cells using `colspan` (and the same for the rows without the image, to have the text centered). Isn't it possible to just align the image using CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it meets all the requirements, but this is a possible solution.

Main points:

```
table td {
    position:relative;
}

table td a {
    margin: 0px 20px;
}

/* Image vertically aligned */
table tbody img {
  position:absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top:-5px; /* half image... */
}
```

Complete code

```css
table {
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: small;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 98%;
  animation-name: animWidth;
  animation-duration: 10s;
}

@keyframes animWidth {
  0% {width: 98%}
  50% {width: 40%}
  100% {width: 98%}
}

table th,
table td {
    
  /* Default text alignment */
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;

  /* Separate border */
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  padding: 2px;
}

/* Header */
table th {
  background: #0093DD;
  color: white;
}

/* Footer */
table tfoot::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 8px;
}

table tfoot td:first-child {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 16px;
}

table tfoot td:last-child {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 16px;
}

/* Alternate line colors */
table tbody tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background: #EFEFEF;
}


/* Description column left aligned */
table tbody td:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: left;
}

/* Columns width */
table tbody td:nth-child(1),
table tbody td:nth-child(5) {
  width: 90px;
}

table tbody td:nth-child(2) {
  width: auto;
}

table tbody td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 90px;
}

table tbody td:nth-child(4) {
  width: 160px;
}

table td {
    position:relative;
}

table td a {
    margin: 0px 20px;
}

/* Image vertically aligned */
table tbody img {
  position:absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top:-5px; /* half image... */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>SKU</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Availability</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img title="Out of stock" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhDAAMAMQAAPcGB3lxgOzNz4pjcL59hMwrMcIzOvrv7/ELDYtpdaJOWY5fbL43Pp9RXP8AAIBseptVYO0QEo9odMgvNfAMDvUJCvoFBYxhbr5+hXhyge3P0c8pLsUyOPvv7/MLDAAAACH5BAEHAAcALAAAAAAMAAwAAAVM4CFiUhBImCgKybIhEXclgpgoTp5bTXIQg4pORxmQCsMhQ5IBJIkm4dNBOU2mDgPqYnl6HoRDokEZeiC+A2tgoFAMj4RGdSCZJGFRCAA7">
        <a href="">4000.4</a>
      </td>
      <td>Lemon soda</td>
      <td>10/10/2021</td>
      <td>London, United Kingdom</td>
      <td>Waiting</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img title="In stock" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhDAAMAMQAAAD/AGmLdc3sz1GfXH2+hCnPLjPCOu/67wn1CnF5gDe+PmGMbk6iWVWbYAX6BWyAel+ObAzwDmiPdC/INRDtEgrxDAb3B2OKcH6+hc/t0SvMMTLFOO/773J4gQvzDAAAACH5BAEHABwALAAAAAAMAAwAAAVNIMcdmJQkEnaInBBARUVtSyCMAQPsuzMEB8IFweNFLiVNsaiQdCxL44kYBURQkyrAkFo4op4H4RAYRIqeBrAVuBgiEcMjkGGRTKixKAQAOw==">
        <a href="">3000.3</a>
       </td>
      <td>Orange juice</td>
      <td>12/11/2021</td>
      <td>Paris, France</td>
      <td>Shipped</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="">2000.2</a>
       </td>
      <td>An unknown long product to drink when you would like</td>
      <td>09/11/2021</td>
      <td>Berlin, Germany</td>
      <td>Waiting</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img title="Out of stock" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhDAAMAMQAAPcGB3lxgOzNz4pjcL59hMwrMcIzOvrv7/ELDYtpdaJOWY5fbL43Pp9RXP8AAIBseptVYO0QEo9odMgvNfAMDvUJCvoFBYxhbr5+hXhyge3P0c8pLsUyOPvv7/MLDAAAACH5BAEHAAcALAAAAAAMAAwAAAVM4CFiUhBImCgKybIhEXclgpgoTp5bTXIQg4pORxmQCsMhQ5IBJIkm4dNBOU2mDgPqYnl6HoRDokEZeiC+A2tgoFAMj4RGdSCZJGFRCAA7">
        <a href="">1000.1</a>
      </td>
      <td>Pineapple juice 500 ml</td>
      <td>24/12/2021</td>
      <td>&mdash;</td>
      <td>&mdash;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img title="Out of stock" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhDAAMAMQAAPcGB3lxgOzNz4pjcL59hMwrMcIzOvrv7/ELDYtpdaJOWY5fbL43Pp9RXP8AAIBseptVYO0QEo9odMgvNfAMDvUJCvoFBYxhbr5+hXhyge3P0c8pLsUyOPvv7/MLDAAAACH5BAEHAAcALAAAAAAMAAwAAAVM4CFiUhBImCgKybIhEXclgpgoTp5bTXIQg4pORxmQCsMhQ5IBJIkm4dNBOU2mDgPqYnl6HoRDokEZeiC+A2tgoFAMj4RGdSCZJGFRCAA7">
        <a href="">1001.5</a>
      </td>
      <td>This product doesn't have any icon and should use all the space</td>
      <td>03/12/2021</td>
      <td>&mdash;</td>
      <td>Waiting</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="">&lt; Prev</a></td>
      <td colspan="3">Products 1-5 of 2124</td>
      <td><a href="">Next &gt;</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Seems to work quite well, apart if the text inside `<a>` is too much long: in that case it goes under the image instead of incrementing the column width. But probably this is not possible to fulfill?

Comment: You can add a margin to your link, if the dot image is 20px width, add `margin: 0px 20px;' to your link. In this way you can have always a min lateral margin for your image.

Comment: @virtualdj I've updated the answer with your request and a bit of interactivity to test if the `margin` works

Answer (score 1):

You can use a situation like below: Use `position: absolute;` for the image (and `position: relative` for that cell) and vertically center it with `top: 50%;` and `transform: translateY(-50%);`. Then the text can be centered with the usual methods. The only thing you'll need is a set `width` for that cell, but it seems your contents in that cell and the images are so that this can be reliably "pre-calculated"

EDIT / addition: To allow longer text without overlapping the image, you can use a correspondig side padding in that cell – the cell will grow accordingly beyond its defined `width` if necessary.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
}

td:first-child {
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 40px;
}

td:first-child img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img title="Out of stock" src="...">
      <!-- This image may or may not exist -->
      <a href="">4000.4</a>
    </td>
    <td>Lemon soda</td>
    <td>10/10/2021</td>
    <td>London, United Kingdom</td>
    <td>Waiting</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
      <img title="Out of stock" src="...">
      <!-- This image may or may not exist -->
      <a href="">4000000000000.5</a>
    </td>
    <td>Lemon soda</td>
    <td>10/10/2021</td>
    <td>London, United Kingdom</td>
    <td>Waiting</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is useful too, but I have to choose one. The plus of your answer is that the `translateY` avoids to hardcode the height of the image, while Baro's answer applied the margin to the `a` which seems better.